# Is there a simple way to create rounded corners with Processing?

Tags: java, image-processing, processing

I've started to use Processing in attempt to draw interactive diagrams. The first step I'd like to do would be to create 'nodes' for certain things represented as rectangles with rounded corners on.

However, it seems this isn't a simple task. The usual `rect` constructor that I know of doesn't have the right method - and attempting to do it manually using `beginShape()` and `curveVertex()` is proving an absolute nightmare.

Does anyone know if there's an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found the answer to this whilst I was doing some more research before I posted this question - I figured I'd post it anyway in case anyone might need it.

It turns out, it's quite easy to do - it was just me being a little dumb.

`rect()` in the Processing API specifies an eight-parameter constructor (in its [Reference / API](http://processing.org/reference/rect_.html)) which allows you to specify the radius for each corner of the rectangle:

`rect(x, y, width, height, top-left radius, top-right radius, bottom-right radius, bottom-left radius);`

Comment: beat me to it... saw this last night but was just on my phone...Note that this is only in Processing 2.0+, it won't work in 1.5.1 and earlier...